# Does poking a Facebook user lift their ban?

Tags: facebook

If someone was reported by other users on Facebook, Facebook will issue a temporary warning/ban.

Many users, when faced with this problem, ask their friends to comment/poke/share etc their posts to lift the ban.

However, I can't find any reference to any Facebook help page that explains this.

Does this method actually work? If so, is there any reference to what is the best action (preferably from Facebook docs)? If not, is there any other method that works?

Comment: Good question, but I very much doubt it. If it were as easy as having your friends "poke" you to get around a ban, that would defeat the whole purpose of the ban.

Comment: @ale I thought about that too. One case which I think this makes sense is when the user is reported as "fake account". The reaction from friends could be understood as vouching for him. However, this is just a theory.

Comment: Meh. Those other account could be just as fake.

Comment: yes. But what makes me think of that is that it is similar to the reporting mechanism. It uses a combination of the number of reports, time of reporting and other stuff. It makes sense that there is a similar procedure to "unreport" and the final outcome of the user depends on a balance between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

Banned for using Facebook or a feature cannot lifted before the time period given. A user has to wait till that time.

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/116393198446749/?ref=u2u):

> Facebook has policies in place to stop behavior that other people may find annoying or abusive. We've determined that you used a feature in a way that could be considered abusive, even if you didn't mean to.
>
> A few things to keep in mind about your block:
>
> - Blocks are temporary and can last a few hours or a few days
> - We can't lift this block for any reason